# Segmentation fault when pointer used as key points to something in std::unordered_map

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, segmentation-fault, unordered-map

I was testing `std::unordered_map`s to get used to them before actually using them in a project.

And I noticed that, if I use pointers as keys, I get a segfault error when the pointer used as the key actually points to a value. This is my code:

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    std::unordered_map<int*, int> map;

    int* key;
    //*key = 18;

    map[key] = 1893;

    printf("%d\n", map[key]);
}
```

Now, if I uncomment that commented line, I get a segmentation fault error, while if I leave it commmented, everything works perfectly. Why does this happen?

Comment: you forgot to allocate memory to the pointer. `int *key = new int`

Comment: The commented line dereferences an uninitialized pointer, how do you expect that to work?

Comment: Have a look at this [pointer tutorial](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/). This explains all you need to know, why this won't work.

Comment: "everything works perfectly" - I suppose that depends on how liberal your definition of "works perfectly" is. The value of `key` as presented in the code is *indeterminate*. Usage of the value of `key`, therefore, invokes *undefined behavior*. That the code doesn't "crash" doesn't mean it "works". It means you were (un)lucky that invoking undefined behavior didn't manifest as a crash. For more info, see: [Is reading an indeterminate value undefined behavior?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4279264/is-reading-an-indeterminate-value-undefined-behavior)

Comment: The code should work without segfault, and it does work as expected on my Linux system, both in g++ and clang, even with -O3 optimization. Please check if what crashes is indeed your sample code and not some other program.

Comment: @olpa it works _with_ the comment, or _without_ the comment?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1597405/what-happens-to-a-declared-uninitialized-variable-in-c-does-it-have-a-value

Comment: Works when commented-out. And when the instruction `*key=18` is active, it must fail. The error has nothing to do with unordered_map, the error is the dereference of the unintialized pointer. To repair, use something like this: `int xxx = 18; int *key = &xxx`.

Comment: You have to assign `key` a value before you attempt to use its value! `*key = 18;` uses the value of `key` to know where to store the 18 -- except it has no value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declared a pointer, not an `int`. The pointer points to nowhere, as you did not initialize it. There is no place to write the `18` to, because the pointer doesn't point to any space.

Note that your issue is completely unrelated to unordered maps.
`int * key; *key = 18;` will dump in any context.

Use either
`int key; key = 18;`,
or if you really want `key` to be a pointer:
`int * key = new int; key = 18;`