# Trouble Understanding sprintf with 'char * str + int'

Tags: c++, printf

I was looking at a project and came across the following code and am unable to figure out what the [sprintf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf/) is doing in this context and was hoping someone might be able to help me figure it out.

```
char storage[64];
int loc = 0;
int size = 35;

sprintf(storage+(loc),"A");  //Don't know what this does
loc+=1;
sprintf(storage+(loc),"%i", size);  //Don't know what this does
loc+=4;
sprintf(storage+(loc), "%i", start); //Don't know what this does

start += size;
loc += 3;
```

The code later does the following in another part

```
string value;
int actVal;
int index = 0;
for(int j = index+1; j < index+4; j++)
{
    value += storage[j]; 
}
istringstream iss;
iss.str(value);
iss >> actVal; //Don't understand how this now contains size
```

The examples I have seen online regarding sprintf never covered that the above code was possible, but the program executes fine. I just can't figure out how the "+loc" affects storage in this instance and how the values would be saved/stored. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: the short answer is any pointer plus an integer returns a pointer advanced that many elements. its basically telling sprintf to start printing `loc` spaces into the buffer.

Comment: Why would the same codebase use `istringstream` in one part, but not `ostringstream`, thus not needing to use `sprintf`?

Comment: `sprintf` is a C library function, that is of very little use in modern C++ code, except for creating multiple opportunities of buffer overflows; and serves very little purpose other than being a never-ending source of bugs.

Comment: You could rewrite `storage+(loc)` as `&(storage[loc])`.

Comment: Just hope `size` is between [-999, 9999]

Comment: `storage + (loc)` is equivalent to `&storage[loc]`.   Since `storage` is an array, `sprintf(storage+loc, "A")` writes the character `'A' to `storage[loc]` and (since `sprintf()` appends a trailing `'\0'`) a `'\0'` to `storage[loc+1]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ugly code! Regardless, for the first part, `storage+(loc)` == `&storage[loc]`. You end up with a string `"A35\0<unknown_value>1234\0"`, assuming `start = 1234`, or in long form:

```
sprintf(&storage[0],"A");
sprintf(&storage[1],"%i", size);
sprintf(&storage[5], "%i", start);
```

For the second part, assuming we have the `"A35\0<unknown_value>1234\0"` above, we get:

```
 value += '3';
 value += '5';
 value += '\0';
 value += '<unknown_value>'; // This might technically be undefined behaviour
```

So now `value = "35"`. [1]

```
iss.str(value);
iss >> actVal;
```

This turns the string into an input stream and reads out the first string representing an integer, `"35"`, and converts it into an integer, giving us basically `actVal = atoi(value.c_str());`.

Finally, [according to this page](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4279264/1270789), yes, reading an uninitialised ("indeterminate value" is the official term) array element is undefined behaviour thus should be avoided.

[1] Note that in a usual implementation, there is a theoretical 10/256 chance that the `<unknown_value>` could contain an ASCII digit, so `value` could end up being between `350` and `359`, which is obviously not a good outcome and is why one shouldn't ignore undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

The function `sprintf()` works just like `printf()`, except the result is not printed in stdout, rather it is store in a string variable. I suggest you read the `sprintf()` man page carefully:

https://linux.die.net/man/3/sprintf

Even if you are not on a Linux, that function is pretty much similar across different platforms, be it Windows, Mac or other animals. That said, this piece of code you have presented seems to be unnecessarily complicated.

The first part could be written as:

```
sprintf(storage,"A %i %i", size, start);
```

For a similar-but-not-equal result, but then again, it all depends on what exactly the original programmer intended this storage area to hold. As Ken pointed out, there are some undefined bytes and behaviors coming from this code as-is.

Answer (score 0):

From the standard:

> `int sprintf ( char * str, const char * format, ... );`
>
> Write formatted data to string
>   Composes a string with the same text that would be printed if format was used on printf, but instead of being printed, the content is stored as a C string in the buffer pointed by str.
>
> `sprintf(storage+(loc),"A");`

writes "A" into a buffer called `storage`. The `storage+(loc)` is pointer arithmetic. You're specifying which index of the char array you're writing into. So, `storage = "A"`.

> `sprintf(storage+(loc),"%i", size);`

Here you're writing `size` into storage[1]. Now `storage = "A35\0"`, `loc = 1`, and so on.

Your final value of `storage = "A35\0<garbage><value of start>\0"`

> actVal: Don't understand how this now contains size

The for loop goes through `storage[1]` through `storage[5]`, and builds up `value` using the contents of `storage`. `value` contains the string `"35\0<garbage>"`, and `iss.str(value)` strips it down to `"35\0"`.

> `iss >> actVal`

If you have come across `std::cin`, it's the same concept. The first string containing an integer value is written into actVal.