# c++ very strange numbers

Tags: c++

```
void mult(int number2, int argc, char** argv)
{
    for (int i = 4; i < argc; i++) {
        double number3 = atof(argv[i]);
        double number2 = number2 * number3;
        cout << number2 << endl;
    }
}
```

my input is

```
./calc1 * 1 2 4 5 6
```

when I run this program ,output is :

```
2.07418e-317
4.14837e-317
1.65935e-316
8.29674e-316
4.97804e-315
```

ı am using gedit.

Comment: `double number2=number2*number3;` typo, the first number on the RHS should be `number3`.

Answer (score 1):

```
double number2 = number2 * number3;
```

you need to initialize `number2` with some value otherwise it contains a garbage value which is getting multiplied with `number3`

split above statement into two statements

```
double number2 = /*some value to initialize number2*/;
number2 *= number3;    //now perform multiplication
```

Additionally, `number2` is being passed into function `mult` as an argument, and you are also declaring a new variable with the same name `number2` inside `mult` function.

Comment: sorry It is my mistake I call this function with int number1=1;
mult(number1,argc,argv);

Answer (score 0):

```
double number2 = number2 * number3;
```

You're accessing `number2` before initializing it, [which causes undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4279264/3425536).