# Global/Static variables initialization issue with __attribute__((constructor)) in shared library

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-libraries

I meet an issue with global/static variables' initialization with `__attribute__((constructor))` in shared library， that certain variables seem to be initialized twice.

Below are code snippets:

**shared.cpp**

```
struct MyStruct
{
  MyStruct(int s = 1)
  : s(s) {
    printf("%s, this: %p, s=%d\n", __func__, this, s);
  }
  ~MyStruct() {
    printf("%s, this: %p, s=%d\n", __func__, this, s);
  }
  int s;
};

MyStruct* s1 = nullptr;
std::unique_ptr<MyStruct> s2 = nullptr;
std::unique_ptr<MyStruct> s3;
MyStruct s4;

void onLoad() __attribute__((constructor));
void onLoad()
{
  s1 = new MyStruct;
  s2 = std::make_unique<MyStruct>();
  s3 = std::make_unique<MyStruct>();
  s4 = MyStruct(2);

  printf("&s1: %p, &s2: %p, &s3: %p\n", &s1, &s2, &s3);
  printf("s1: %p, s2: %p, s3: %p\n", s1, s2.get(), s3.get());
  printf("s4: %p, s4.s: %d\n", &s4, s4.s);
}

extern "C" void foo()
{
  printf("&s1: %p, &s2: %p, &s3: %p\n", &s1, &s2, &s3);
  printf("s1: %p, s2: %p, s3: %p\n", s1, s2.get(), s3.get());
  printf("s4: %p, s4.s: %d\n", &s4, s4.s);
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <dlfcn.h>

using Foo = void(*)(void);

int main()
{
  printf("Calling dlopen...\n");
  void* h = dlopen("./libshared.so", RTLD_NOW | RTLD_GLOBAL);
  Foo f = reinterpret_cast<Foo>(dlsym(h, "foo"));
  printf("\nCalling foo()...\n");
  f();
  return 0;
}
```

Compiled with

```
$ g++ -fPIC -shared -std=c++14 shared.cpp -o libshared.so
$ g++ -std=c++14 -o main main.cpp -ldl
```

The output:

```
Calling dlopen...
MyStruct, this: 0x121b200, s=1
MyStruct, this: 0x121b220, s=1
MyStruct, this: 0x121b240, s=1
MyStruct, this: 0x7ffc19736910, s=2
~MyStruct, this: 0x7ffc19736910, s=2
&s1: 0x7fb1fe487190, &s2: 0x7fb1fe487198, &s3: 0x7fb1fe4871a0
s1: 0x121b200, s2: 0x121b220, s3: 0x121b240
s4: 0x7fb1fe4871a8, s4.s: 2
MyStruct, this: 0x7fb1fe4871a8, s=1

Calling foo()...
&s1: 0x7fb1fe487190, &s2: 0x7fb1fe487198, &s3: 0x7fb1fe4871a0
s1: 0x121b200, s2: (nil), s3: 0x121b240
s4: 0x7fb1fe4871a8, s4.s: 1
~MyStruct, this: 0x7fb1fe4871a8, s=1
~MyStruct, this: 0x121b240, s=1
```

The value of `s1` and `s3` are expected.

But `s2` and `s4` behave weird.

- `s2.get()` should be `0x121b220`, but in `foo()` it becomes `nullptr`;
- `s4`'s value is printed as `s4.s: 2` in `onLoad()`, but after that its constructor is called with default value `s=1`, then in `foo()` its value is `s=1`.

Putting the variables in anonymous namespace has the same result.

What's wrong with `s2` and `s4`?

My OS: Ubuntu 16.04.2, GCC: 5.4.0

Comment: I don't see any evidence that anything's "initialized twice"

Comment: The sequence of ctor/dtor calls make it appear that `s4` was never constructed before `onLoad()` got called, but then gets constructed after. The first three ctor calls are from your heap allocations. The fourth is the temporary `MyStruct(2)` and the following dtor call is the temporary being destroyed. There's no default ctor call for `s4` -- until after the final `printf()`. That's strange indeed. That's probably why `s4.s` becomes 1, though.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition Yeah, that's why I say it *seems*, I'm just not sure. For example `s4` seems to be constructed twice, or it is used before constructed, then it's constructed...

Comment: No it doesn't. The output shows precisely the right number of calls to the `MyStruct` constructor.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition It does, but not in the right order. We are compiling without `-O` so we don't get copy elision. See my comment. `s4` does appear to be copy-assigned from the temporary prior to its default construction, which happens after `onLoad()` returns, clobbering the value 2 with 1.

Comment: @cdhowie: Yes, I read your comment, which is correct

Comment: [This](https://pastebin.com/1avcsnX6) is how I interpret the sequence of events, anyway, if this makes it clearer. This does seem like a GCC bug, as the documentation for `__attribute__((constructor))` implies that it follows the standard static initialization order rules; that is, things are initialized/called in the order they are declared. But `onLoad()` is declared after `s4`, so we would expect `s4` to be initialized first.

Comment: I'm not sure but maybe you are looking for `__atribute__((init_priority(N)))` for your `s` variables [reference](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.2/gcc/C---Attributes.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the discussion on [this GCC bug report](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=52477) and [this follow-up doc patch](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-patches/2017-03/msg00863.html) it seems that what you're seeing is unspecified behavior in GCC (not a bug).

> However, the order in which constructors for C++ objects with static storage duration and functions decorated with attribute `constructor` are invoked is unspecified. In mixed declarations, attribute `init_priority` can be used to impose a specific ordering.

It seems in this case that a segfault was narrowly avoided, as assigning to an uninitialized `std::unique_ptr` could cause `delete` to be invoked for an uninitialized pointer member.  GCC's unspecified behavior translates into undefined behavior (in this particular case) according to the C++ specification, because it's [undefined behavior to read from an uninitialized variable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4279264/501250) (except for an uninitialized `unsigned char`).

Anyway, to correct this problem you do indeed need to use `__attribute((init_priority))` to order initialization of your statically-declared objects before the constructor function.

Comment: I still consider this as GCC bug, since the bug is still not closed. Using `__attribute__((init_priority(101)))` does resolve the issue.