# Is it allowed to assign from an object that has some indeterminate values?

Tags: c++, initialization

Consider the following class, which can either be in a "non-empty" or "empty" state, and in the "empty" state the other member is default initialized (hence has an indeterminate value):

```
struct MaybeInt {
  bool has_value;
  int value;

  MaybeInt()      : has_value(false) {}
  MaybeInt(int v) : has_value(true ), value(v) {}
};
```

Is it allowed to assign from a default-constructed `MaybeInt`, as in:

```
MaybeInt empty, another;
another = empty; // OK?
```

How about construction?

```
MaybeInt empty, another(empty); // OK?
```

Does the answer change if `MaybeInt::value` has type `char`?

Comment: related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4279264/is-reading-an-indeterminate-value-undefined-behavior trying to find a better target

Comment: @NathanOliver I don't think that is a dupe: the correct answer (by Shafik) relies on the standard text "If an indeterminate value is produced by an evaluation, the behavior is undefined",  however it's not immediately clear that `value` is evaluated by the assignment in this question

Answer (score 2):

`another = empty` is indeed UB because `empty.value` has an [indeterminate value](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.init#12) and because the [implicitly defined copy constructor of a class](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.copy.ctor#14) copies all members.

The trick is to place the member `value` in a union. This way the [implicitly defined copy constructor of the union](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.copy.ctor#15) copies the [object representation](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.types#4) :

```
struct MaybeInt {
  bool has_value;
  union {
    int value;
    char _dumb;
    };

  MaybeInt()      : has_value(false) {}
  MaybeInt(int v) : has_value(true ), value(v) {}
  };
```

**NB**: This is a low level trick to have an optional that is trivially copyable. This is realy important for code execution speed. This class can be passed through function call on a cpu register, while it would be impossible if it were not trivially copyable.

Comment: Clever trick but annoying that it is necessary... I propose that the standard could "specialize" `std::optional<T>` to be trivially-copyable iff `T` is

Comment: `char _dumb;` is unnecesseary, right?

Answer (score -1):

Your code results in undefined behaviour.

```
MaybeInt empty, another;
another = empty;
```

OK. `another` has the same undefined value that `empty` had. Technically working, leading to bugs in practise.

```
MaybeInt empty, another(empty);
```

`empty` contains an undefined value, and this is copied to `another` which has the same value, only now your class *thinks* it is defined.

Use [std::optional](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional), 
everything which should be optional is solved in a standard way. (C++ 17)

```
optional<int> x; // empty or not, you can use `value_or()` to get a default value.
```

Comment: So it is it "technically correct" or "your code results in undefined behaviour" because those sound like opposites.

Comment: Technically working i meant. The code will compile and *may* or may *not* work correctly