# Why is 'int i = i;' legal?

Tags: c++, selfinitialization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [int var = 1; void main() { int i = i; }](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3173462/int-var-1-void-main-int-i-i)

The following code can pass compiling under both g++ and Visual C++.  Why is it legal?  It looks unreasonable, and may cause hidden bugs.

```
int main() {
  int i = i;
}
```

Comment: For me its not illegal,  its just an abuse of notation.

Comment: It evaluates as (i) `int i` (ii) `i = i` in that order

Comment: I think for the same reason that just `int i;` without ever assigning `i` is legal.

Comment: @asmeurer but then it's illegal to use `i`.

Answer (score 47):

**EDIT:** It's **syntactically legal**, but results in undefined behavior if you use `x`.

It's **not** legal because you're assigning an uninitialized variable with another (well, the same) uninitialized variable. Just because it compiles doesn't mean it's legal. It's valid C++ syntax, yes, but not legal.

The right hand side of the assignment operator must be fully evaluated at the time of the assignment. In this case, that's `i`, which isn't initialized.

Credits to Steve Jessop, who dug up the quote:

**4.1/1, lvalue-to-rvalue conversion**

> [...] if the object is uninitialized, a program that necessitates this
>   conversion has undefined behavior.

Comment: That argument is circular, having a variable whose value is undefined is certainly not illegal. Compare it to just plain `int i;` which also leaves `i` with an undefined value.

Comment: @nhahtdh that doesn't mean it's legal.

Comment: Luchian, it compiles, and there's nothing in the spec that disallows it.

Comment: @unwind yes, and assigning that `i` to something else is also not legal. So why would this be?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: Legal in what sense? I get the idea that it's totally wrong to do so, though. But the compiler happily compiles it.

Comment: @nhahtdh the compiler also compiles returning a local variable by reference, but it's also not legal.

Comment: It's 100% correct---the code is illegal.  The answer might be slightly better if he's mentioned the keywords "undefined behavior", but he's covered all of the important points: valid syntax, but not legal; `i` evaluated before being initialized; etc.

Comment: @nhahtdh In the sense defined in the standard, what else? **Whether it compiles or not is irrelevant for legality.** Otherwise we’d have no undefined behaviour. **Stop (down)voting if you have no clue, people!**

Comment: @Luchian To be honest, I’m not actually sure whether this code is legal or not – reading the value of `x` afterwards certainly is UB. This initialisation? No idea. But all the arguments mentioned here claiming that this is legal are just wrong.

Comment: @KonradRudolph the only arguments here are that the compiler accepts it. :) Which is definitely not a valid one.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I actually posted a similar question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9868921/is-x-x-x-x-legal-c - that's why I remembered this isn't illegal. If it is however, I'll have to go back to that.

Comment: If it helps: 4.1/1, lvalue-to-rvalue conversion, "if the object is uninitialized, a program that necessitates this conversion has undefined behavior". You cannot read uninitialized objects, so unless you care to argue that `i` is not uninitialized when it is read in its own initializer, I don't think there's a huge amount of debate what the standard says about this case.

Comment: @SteveJessop thank you, I hope you don't mind if I put this in the answer.

Comment: I think you must clasrify what exactly you mean by _valid_ and _legal_. Many people seem to confuse the two words.

Comment: @Salman: Indeed, the terms need some clarification. The code may be treated illegal only if it is actually executed. For example, if main() isn't defined in global scope and is never called, the code is absolutely legal. Any cases of UB in unevaluated operands are legal, etc.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the code is *legal* in my jurisdiction. It is also *well-formed* as far as the C++ standard is concerned. The behavior of such program, however, is not defined by the standard (i.e. it invokes *undefined behavior*).

Comment: I'm not clear on this concept "legal" in program text. Where is the law book that defines what is legal and what is not? Do the SO police prosecute you if you code something that's not legal?

Answer (score 17):

The reason it's allowed by the syntax is that there are some odd cases where you might conceivably want to use a variable by pointer or reference in its own initializer:

```
struct ThingManager {
    void *thing;
    ThingManager(void *thing) : thing(thing) {}
    void Speak() {
        if (thing == (void*)this) {
            std::cout << "I'm managing myself\n";
        } else {
            std::cout << "I'm managing " << thing << "\n";
        }
    }
};

ThingManager self_manager(&self_manager);
ThingManager other_manager(&self_manager);
```

So C++ lets you refer to an object in its own initializer expression (its name is in scope). Then as ever in C++, it's your problem to make sure you don't actually use an uninitialized value (your example, `int i = i;` does use an uninitialized value).

You compiler might help with identifying uses of uninitialized values, but the standard doesn't require it to.

Comment: This is the only answer that shows why it actually *needs* to be legal C++. Thanks,

Answer (score 8):

You can let `g++` warn you about this use case with `-Winit-self` (in conjunction with `-Wuninitialized`), and if you treat warnings as errors, it should satisfy your itch.

This technique of using the copy constructor to self-initialize is sometimes used to suppress a global object's default constructor/initializer from executing. This may be necessary if the global object's default constructor is just to `0` initialize the object, but the object got used before the constructor would have been executed. As a throwback to C, globals are `0` initialized at program start, and then the C++ runtime begins to execute global constructors. For those narrow cases where the defined constructor that would have executed is only to `0` out the object, the self initialization does not do any harm.

In the general case, copy constructor self-initialization is bad practice, since it generally would cause the same sorts of problems that using an uninitialized variable would cause (that is, undefined behavior). In the particular example in the OP's question, `i` is local to `main`, and is therefore uninitialized. The result of reading an uninitialized variable is always undefined behavior.

Comment: It doesn't seem to generate any warning with `-Winit-self` for me, though.

Comment: _If_ the object has a user defined type, and the constructor takes the instance by reference, and never dereferences it (in the constructor), then the code is legal.  (The user defined constructor could save the address, for example.)

Comment: @JamesKanze: Yes, I read your interesting example. But, I was only talking about the copy constructor. Thanks and regards

Answer (score 3):

You can use any previously declared variable as an initialiser of another variable.

In this case as soon as the compiler parses `int i` it adds that to the symbol table, so when it sees the `= i` initialiser, the symbol can be resolved from the preceding declaration.

It is not an error because the compiler can make sense of it in that it can generate code that unambiguously does exactly what the source code specifies, even if it is semantically suspect.  The philosophy of C and C++ is to compile anything that can possibly be compiled syntactically.  Semantic errors generally issue only warnings, and only then if such warnings are enabled.