# lambda capture during initialization should be an error

Tags: c++, lambda, initialization, c++14

What I'm *trying* to do is eat exceptions when constructing an object that *may* be invalid. It'd be perfect for use of `std::optional`, but I don't believe the omission of `std::optional` changes the error I see: the object is being captured and used before it's been initialized. I don't believe it should be captured in the first place because we haven't reached a *sequence point* to the best of my knowledge (does a lambda initialization count as a sequence point?). Moreover, the bug is IMO easily catchable human error (and even does get caught... depending upon circumstances).

How (more importantly, *why*) is the lambda able to capture and use the not-yet-initialized `foo`?

https://godbolt.org/g/IwcHrV

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void foo() {
  string foo = [&]()->string{
    // using foo before it's been initialized == undefined behavior
    auto guessed_foo = to_string(1234);
    if ( begin(foo) == end(foo) ) {
      return guessed_foo;
    }
    return {};
  }();
}
```

> Compiler exited with result code 0

But... replacing the declaration of `string foo` with `auto foo` *does* appear to cause an error similar to what I'd like to see.

https://godbolt.org/g/GfE4WH

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void foo() {
  auto foo = [&]()->string{
    auto guessed_foo = to_string(1234);
    if ( begin(foo) == end(foo) ) {
      return guessed_foo;
    }
    return {};
  }();
}
```

> error: variable 'foo' declared with 'auto' type cannot appear in its own initializer

Note that I found this using GCC 6.2 on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. The configuration in Godbolt is using clang 3.9.1. Both are configured for c++14.

So my questions are:

- Why is the lambda capture for an initialization of a non-auto-declared variable able to capture and use the (not-yet-initialized) variable?
- Why does `auto` get (in my opinion, correctly) caught and errored?
- Moreover, why the difference between the above two? It sounds like compiler bugs, but... is there something specific in the standard declaring this to be correct behavior?
- This could be taken as an argument *for* `auto` keyword?

Comment: highly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11186261/why-is-int-i-i-legal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second snippet runs into [[dcl.spec.auto]/10](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.spec.auto#10):

> If the type of an entity with an undeduced placeholder type is needed
>   to determine the type of an expression, the program is ill-formed.

The type of `foo` is needed to determine the type of the expression `foo` within the lambda body, but at that point you haven't deduced `foo`'s type yet, so the program is ill-formed.

---

As to why you are allowed to capture something before its initialization, see generally [Why is 'int i = i;' legal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11186261/why-is-int-i-i-legal). We have many examples of recursive lambdas using `std::function`:

```
std::function<void(int)> foo = [&foo](int i){ return foo(i - 1); };
```

Comment: Okay, so then why does `-Winit-self -Wuninitialized` emit a diagnostic for `int i = i;` but does _not_ from the lambda expression? https://godbolt.org/g/qC2iao

Comment: @inetknght These are best-effort warnings, not guaranteed.