# Can't use captured variable before deduction of auto

Tags: c++, lambda, c++14

This question is related to this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43052499/lambda-capture-during-initialization-should-be-an-error).

Why doesn't this compile:

```
int main() {
    auto foo = [&]() -> int {foo; return {};}();
    (void)(foo);
}
```

[LIVE on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a111f38dd58e6b06)

Error:

```
main.cpp: In lambda function:
main.cpp:3:30: error: use of 'foo' before deduction of 'auto'
     auto foo = [&]() -> int {foo; return {};}();
                              ^~~
```

But casting foo to the resulting type allows compilation:

```
int main() {
    auto foo = [&]() -> int {int(foo); (void)(foo);return {};}();
    (void)(foo);
}
```

[LIVE on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/49f0ae597d720930)

Comment: I don't get it. `foo` is a lambda returning an `int`, not an `int`... Did you meant to invoke the lambda `auto foo = [&](){...}();`?

Comment: @YSC Sorry, editing.

Answer (score 5):

Vexing parses again. If something can be a declaration, it is a declaration.

`int(foo);` is `int (foo);` is `int foo;`. Then the `foo` in `(void)(foo);` refers to the `int`.

---

The first snippet runs into [[dcl.spec.auto]/10](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.spec.auto#10):

> If the type of an entity with an undeduced placeholder type is needed
>   to determine the type of an expression, the program is ill-formed.

The type of `foo` is needed to determine the type of the expression `foo` within the lambda body, but at that point you haven't deduced `foo`'s type yet, so the program is ill-formed.

Comment: As I get it, it's only half an answer. I guess OP would like to know a workaround and use `foo` inside the lambda.

Comment: I understand. But why doesn't the first example compile since foo type should be known since lambda has explicit return type?

Comment: @BlackMoses To add a bit more info: a lambda's type depends on its body (for example, figuring out which entities are captured and become members of the generated class). Its type is not determined solely by its parameters and return type. You then made its body depend on its type by your capture.