# Using a pointer in the same statement of its declaration

Tags: c++, pointers, initialization

I came across some code where a pointer was used on the same line of its declaration. This is the essential SSCCE for it:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

struct C 
{
    uint32_t a;
};

int main() {
    C* pC = (C*) malloc(sizeof(*pC));     // <---- ???
    pC->a = 42;

    std::cout << pC << std::endl;
    std::cout << pC->a << std::endl;

    free(pC);
}
```

When I try to do something similar with a `uint32` (insert before the `free()`):

```
uint32_t a = a + pC->a;
std::cout << a << std::endl;
```

Then either nothing is printed for this statement, or while debugging a random value is stored in `a` and VS2015 gives me a runtime warning. Errorlevel after execution is 3. I know this can't work.

Why can I use the pointer? Is it even legal? Why isn't the compiler complaining about such statements? Is the statement split into multiple statements behind the scenes?

Comment: The pointer's value is not being used in the SSCE, only its type is being used -- `sizeof(*pC)` is the same thing as `sizeof(C)`. Using something's *value* and using its *type* are very different.

Comment: `malloc` and `free`? Are programming C or C++???

Comment: C++. As I said, this is not my own code, I only stripped it down to the essential parts to get an SSCCE. I know I should be using new/delete. Also, can the downvoter explain why this wouldn't be a good question?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I understand, the point here is that `pC` is being declared and initialized on that particular line of code, and `pC` is immediately referred as well. I have a Java background, a similar construction would not be possible in Java, hence my question.

Comment: @Timmos It's not being referred really. Only its type is being used. It doesn't have a value yet, but it does have a type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`uint32_t a = a + pC->a;` gives you bad results because you are using the *value* of `a` before it is initialized which is undefined behavior.  For more on this see [Why is 'int i = i;' legal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11186261/why-is-int-i-i-legal)

`C* pC = (C*) malloc(sizeof(*pC));` on the other hand is not using the *value* of `pC` in the initialization.  `sizeof`, when applied to a named variable, gives you the size of its type.  This is an *unevaluated operand* which means it is not evaluated.  So we are not using the value of `*pC` but instead we are getting the size of what the pointer points to which is `C`.

One reason you would want to do this is if you changed the type of `pC` you do not have to change the `sizeof` part.  If you had

```
C* pC = (C*) malloc(sizeof(C));
```

Then you need to remember to change `sizeof(C)` part when changing the type of `pC`.

---

Of course all of this can be avoided using a `std::unique_ptr` like

```
auto pC = std::make_unique<C>();
                           ^ here is the only place you have to specify the type
```

Comment: Very concise yet useful answer with a nice use case. Would polymorphism also be a good use case for prefering `*pC` over `C`?

Comment: @Timmos Probably not since you normally have a base class pointer and dereferencing that just gives you the base, the the derived type you want to create.

Comment: I just found out that sizeof is a compile time operator, so no, polymorphism would not work, because the compiler only sees the base type.