# How am I able to use an incomplete class as an argument in itself?

Tags: c++

```
struct test{
 void call(test t1){
   //
 }
};
```

I have asked a similar question and found a few other links such as:

[How am I able to use a class as a function parameter in itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70683050/how-am-i-able-to-use-a-class-as-a-function-parameter-in-itself)

[Incomplete types in member function definitions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57631441/incomplete-types-in-member-function-definitions)

But none of them answer this question:

The compiler needs to emit code to allocated space on the stack for `t1`, but at that
point `test` is incomplete so how would it know how much space it needs?

Comment: It probably just doesn't generate the function until it's finished parsing the class and knows how big it is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The class `struct test` is not an incomplete type.

From [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type#Incomplete_type):

> **Incomplete type**
>
> - the type void (possibly cv-qualified);
> - incompletely-defined object types
>
>   - class type that has been declared (e.g. by forward declaration) but not defined;
>   - array of unknown bound;
>   - array of elements of incomplete type;
>   - enumeration type from the point of declaration until its underlying type is determined.
>
> All other types are complete.

Test it out yourself, put a test into your `call` function, like:

```
void call(test t1)
{
    std::cout << sizeof t1 << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: maybe i'm thinking too much into how it would be implemented in the compiler. When the compiler is parsing `call`  it hasn't even seen the rest if the struct yet.

Comment: If the compiler parses the declarations before the definitions, then it will know.

Comment: you mean parse the entire struct declaration before function definition?

Comment: Compilation is not single pass.

Comment: Right but when you say compiler parses the declarations, what do you mean by that? you mean declaration of other data types within the struct?

Comment: Compiling is a complex task, every compiler has its own methods. As an example, have a look at https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Passes.html#Passes. As a developer (programmer) it is sufficient to know, that things being used, must have been declared beforehand and not incomplete.

Comment: Im trying to clarify what you mean by **declarations**? i.e in `struct test {int a;}`, `a` is a declaration and compiler will need to read them all first?

Comment: It has to read everything. And no, `a` is not a declaration, `int a` on the other hand is. Have a lokk at the c++ standard, [4 General principles](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/intro) and [5 Lexical conventions](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/lex) for the translation steps.

Comment: right i was also referring to `int a` (I thought that was clear). So compiler needs to read all the declaration of other data in the struct first.

Comment: More or less :) But honestly, if you are interested how the source files are processed, read the provided links. Hope you get an insight from them.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is in the answers of your linked question ([Incomplete types in member function definitions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57631441/incomplete-types-in-member-function-definitions)): the struct *is* complete in the context of the function definition.

Hence the C++ compiler will need to read the entire definition of `struct test` before generating the code of the `call()` function, but that is a compiler implementation issue.

It is also allowed to refer to member variables which are defined later in the `struct` definition:

```
struct test{
 void call(test t1){
   a += t1.a;
 }
 int a;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Compiling a class definition is not a single-pass process.

Member functions are compiled only after it has been determined what the members are, just like if the function definitions were located "outside".

In other words, the compiler doesn't emit any code for the function until the class definition is complete.