# Is it valid to declare a static array with no length, and then define it with a length?

Tags: c++, class, static, declaration, member

Consider this code:

```
class Foo {
   private:
      static char buffer[];
};

char Foo::buffer[100];
```

Is this valid, or do I need to put `buffer[100]` also in the class definition?

Comment: [Declarations of variable inside the class may have incomplete type.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70683050/how-am-i-able-to-use-a-class-as-a-function-parameter-in-itself). So this is valid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A non-inline static data member declared in a class may have an incomplete type.

From the C++ 17 Standard (12.2.3.2 Static data members)

> 2 **The declaration of a non-inline static data member in its class
> definition is not a definition and may be of an incomplete type other
> than cv void.** The definition for a static data member that is not
> defined inline in the class definition shall appear in a namespace
> scope enclosing the member’s class definition. In the definition at
> namespace scope, the name of the static data member shall be qualified
> by its class name using the :: operator. The initializer expression in
> the definition of a static data member is in the scope of its class
> (6.3.7).

So as this declaration (where there is a typo: the type specifies `char` is present twice) in the class definition

```
 static char char buffer[];
```

is not a definition (of an inline data member) it may have an incomplete character array type.

On the other hand, if you want to refer to the array within the class definition it is better to declare it as a complete type. For example this class definition

```
class Foo
{
public:
    void f() const
    {
        std::cout << std::size( buffer ) << '\n';
    }
private:
    static char buffer[];
};
```

will not compile because within the function `f` in this expression `std::size( buffer )` there is used an incomplete array type.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this valid

Yes this is valid **since for `buffer` you have a *declaration* that is not a definition** inside the class. This can be seen from [static member's documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static):

> The declaration inside the class body is not a definition and **may declare the member to be of incomplete type** (other than void), including the type in which the member is declared.

This means that `buffer` can have incomplete type such as `char[]` in its *declaration* inside the class.