Is it safe to reference the parent object during (brace) initialization?
Is it safe to pass a reference of the enclosing object to a subobject's initialization during the initialization of the enclosing object?
struct Foo;
struct Bar {
    Bar(Foo& f) {}
};

struct Foo {
    Bar b;
};

int main() {

    Foo f{
        .b = Bar{f} // line in question
    };
}

Godbolt demo
Foo is not constructed fully when the constructor of Bar runs, is it?

It really depends on what the Bar constructor is doing with the Foo object.

It is syntactically legal, but it depends on what the Bar ctor do with the reference. Similar questioning is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4368361/construct-object-with-itself-as-reference

I am allowed to access all objects that would have been constructed prior b I guess? since the objects are initialized in the declaration order

in .b = .... you give data to construct the b field of f, that implies that f is not constructed at this moment. Only the address of f is valid, and the if constructor of Bar tries to access to any Foo data it is an Undefined Behavior.

@dalfaB I am not even allowed to access subobjects that are delcared prior to b?

@Raildex no, the object is not constructed, here also addresses are valid but no data can be accessed. fields declared before band bases of Foo may be constructed, but I think (a search in the NORM needed) that access to them is an UB

Related. If you attempt to refer to members of f, it will be UB. Note that you are creating Bar{f} before constructing f.

It depends on what the constructor of Bar does to the passed Foo.   Storing a reference or a pointer to the passed Foo is fine (as long as the reference/pointer is only used to access non-static members of that Foo during its lifetime [nominally, after the Foos constructor completes and before that Foos destructor is called].   Accessing members of the Foo outside the Foos lifetime will give undefined behaviour.

In addition to the construction, if Bar were to store a pointer or reference to f, strange things will happen each time f is copied or assigned. Who will adjust the pointers to the new location?
